# What's the best way to handle large timeseries in dask / xarray?

Tags: dask, python-xarray

I've got 17,000 CSV files, each ordered by timestamp (some with missing data). The total CSV files are around 85GB, which is much larger than my 32GB RAM.

I'm trying to figure out the best way to get these into a time-aligned, out-of-memory data structure, such that I can compute things like PCA.

**What's the right approach?**

(I've tried to set up an `xarray.DataSet`, with `dim=(filename, time)`, and then I'm trying to `xr.merge()` on each CSV file into the DataSet, but it gets slower with every insert, and I expect it will crash when RAM runs out.)

Comment: Do you have additional identifier (e.g. ticker if you are working with financial data)? Do files contain overlapping timestamps? (this is important for indexing)

Comment: Yes to both questions!

Comment: OK, that makes it a bit tricky, because of multi-indexing

Comment: I was hoping to create an xarray with dim=2, which seems like it solves this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure about `xarray`-based solution, but if I was doing some work that had two indexes, e.g. ticker and time, then I would re-shape the data by splitting it on ticker and day (or week, or some other level of aggregation that comfortably fits into memory) and saving as time-indexed parquet files where different tickers would be stored in separate folders. Then it would be easier to load it via a series of dask dataframes, such that each dataframe would contain information for one ticker (assuming this is acceptable for the downstream analysis)...

Comment: Is the time dimension not just overlapping but identical for each file? If not, you'll have an even larger problem, as xarray allocates memory for every single (x, y) pair. If the time dimension is identical, you could use xr.open_mfdataset and use the preprocess arg to convert the files to DataArrays, then write to zarr (which can handle distribued writes). Otherwise, I'd use a dask.dataframe with [dask_ml's implementation of PCA](https://ml.dask.org/modules/generated/dask_ml.decomposition.PCA.html)? This could work directly on a dask_dataframe (I think - if not, definitely a dask.array).

Comment: There are several strategies you can try. Using appropriate `dtypes`, using `parquet` instead of `csv` and, eventually, partitioning your data differently. Here some ideas  [link](https://github.com/rpanai/PyDataSTG/blob/master/NycTaxi.ipynb)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `dd.read_csv(...)`.

Dask reads CSVs in a lazily and can perform certain operations in a streaming manner, so you can run an analysis on a larger than memory dataset.

Make sure that Dask is able to properly set divisions when you read in your data.  Once the data is read, check `dd.divisions` and make sure they're values.

You can also use a Dask cluster to access more memory of course.

Those files are really small and Dask typically works best with partitions that are around 100MB.  You might want to compact your data a bit.